# Why the definition works at function level, but not at class level?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using std::vector;
using MATRIX = vector<vector<int>>;


class Matrix {
public:
    MATRIX matrix;
    int row = matrix.size();
    int col = matrix[0].size();

    void repr() {
        for (const vector<int> &sub_arr: matrix) {
            for (int element: sub_arr) {
                std::cout << element << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }

    Matrix operator+(const Matrix &other) {
        std::cout << row << col;
        Matrix new_matrix;

        if (row != other.matrix.size() || col != other.matrix[0].size()) { return {{}}; }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            vector<int> temp_arr;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
                temp_arr.push_back(matrix[i][j] + other.matrix[i][j]);
            }
            new_matrix.matrix.push_back(temp_arr);
        }
        return new_matrix;
    }

    Matrix operator-(const Matrix &other) {
        Matrix new_matrix;
        if (row != other.matrix.size() || col != other.matrix[0].size()) { return {{}}; }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
            vector<int> temp_arr;
            for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
                temp_arr.push_back(matrix[i][j] - matrix[i][j]);
            }
            new_matrix.matrix.push_back(temp_arr);
        }
        return new_matrix;
    }

//    Matrix operator*(const Matrix &other) {}
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};
    Matrix addition = matrix + matrix;
    addition.repr();
}
```

So when I define `row` and `col` at the class level, it doesn't produce any output. But when I define it in the function, it works fine.

I don't understand why it won't work when I define it in the class level. I inserted some debug print statements, and `row` and `col` seem to be correct.

Comment: The initializations of `col` and `row` happens *before* any elements are added to `matrix`.

Comment: But when I print it inside the function (in this case) it outputs 3, 3 for row, col

Comment: Inside *which* function? For what object? When, where and for which object is rather important to know. Can you [edit] your question to show the code where you print the values of `row` and `col`?

Comment: @Ryuga -- Your program  [seg faults](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4796ad1842dfc8c5).  This is all probably due to an out-of-bounds access of the vector.

Comment: `int row = matrix.size(); int col = matrix[0].size();` -- And this is one reason why I am not a gung-ho fan of this type of initialization inside a class.  To me, it is much more clear to declare a constructor, and see the initialization right there (as part of the member initialization list).  Call me old-school, but that has proven to work without surprises.

Comment: As for the problem, in the `main` function when you define the `matrix` object, first `matrix.row` will be initialized; Then `matrix.col` will be initialized (and already here you should see a major problem); And *then* `matrix.matrix` is initialized with the data.

Comment: Ah i c, so is there a way I can initialize then once, because let's say I'm going to create 15 functions, I don't want to initialize them for every function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "natural" solution I can see is to have a constructor taking the matrix data as an argument, and use that as the base for initializations:

```
class Matrix {
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
    MATRIX matrix;

public:
    Matrix()
        : row{ }, col{ }, matrix{ }
    {
    }

    Matrix(MATRIX const& data)
        : row{ data.size() }, col{ data.empty() ? 0 : data[0].size() }, matrix{ data }
    {
    }

    // ...
};
```

Note the check that the passed data isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your `Matrix` object like this:

```
Matrix matrix = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};
```

the [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) takes place, first your `MATRIX matrix;` is initialized, then you assign values 3 and 3 to your `row` and `col`. However, in your second line of `main` and inside `Matrix operator+(const Matrix &other)` you create default constructed  `Matrix` and here you have undefined behavior, because:

```
    int row = matrix.size();  // 0
    int col = matrix[0].size();  // UB, out of bounds access
```

So, for you maybe sometimes it prints something, on other machines it might crash before the addition.

Comment: ah tyvm for explaining.

Comment: @JHBonarius are you sure about it? Because in aggregate initialization docs it states "Each direct public base, (since C++17) array element, or non-static class member, in order of array subscript/appearance in the class definition, is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list." So first vector is initialized, then row and col. Small [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8YT8rh7K7). Let me know if I understood it incorrectly.

Comment: @pptaszni I learned something today, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When `row` and `col` are initialized, `matrix` is still empty. To initialize them after `matrix` is known, write a constructor for your class.

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using MATRIX = vector<vector<int>>;

class Matrix {
public:
    MATRIX matrix;
    int row, col;

    // Constructor
    Matrix(const MATRIX& m)
        : matrix(m), row(m.size()), col(m[0].size())
    {}
};

int main() {
    Matrix matrix = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}};
}
```

Comment: ah thanks for introducing this :)